# Swift. How do I remove the toolbar in an AVPlayerViewController

Tags: swift, toolbar, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, preroll

I'm presenting an `AVPlayerViewController` with an `AVPlayer` and are displaying a pre-roll ad in it, but I want to remove the top and button bar, or make the user unable to dismis the `ViewController` before the ad is done:

[image: Screnshot from iphone]

How do I do that?

here's my code for my AVPlayerViewController implementation:

```
let preRollAdPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()

let player = AVPlayer()
preRollAdPlayer.player = player
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    preRollAdPlayer.delegate = self
}

preRollAdPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = false

self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(preRollAdPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
    self.preRollAdPlayer.playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler({ (error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("Error Message: %@", error)
        } else {
            print("preRoll loaded")
        }

        self.preRollAdPlayer.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("Error Message: %@", error)
            }
        })
    })

})
```

Comment: Edit your post and provide a code snip of your AVPlayerViewController implementation.

Comment: Okay, I just did that

Comment: Did you check that the actual showsPlaybackControls property is set to false ?

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: put a breaking point inside a relevant place (while the video player is shown), and in the console write: **po preRollAdPlayer.showsPlaybackControls** or, you can **print()** the preRollAdPlayer.showsPlaybackControls and look at the console for the result.

Comment: I just did that and it confirmed that showsPlaybackControls was set to false

Comment: Take a look at the link below my answer, perhaps it will assist you.

Comment: Yeah I did but it did not really help me

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, you should use [showsPlaybackControls](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerViewController/showsPlaybackControls) property:

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the player view controller shows playback controls.

Set it to false:

**Swift:**

```
yourAvPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = false
```

**Objective C:**

```
[yourAvPlayer setShowsPlaybackControls:FALSE];
```

Comment: I've just tried that and it dosen't do anything the toolbars are still there

Comment: Have you looked in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090186/hide-controls-in-avplayerviewcontroller-only-at-start